# Creating ID card with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple ID card template with HTML but I got stocked for days looking for how to make passport photograph appear in the photograph box. I also noticed that the print preview of the ID card is not the same as what I see on screen, how can I fix this too please? Below is the code...

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  w = window.open();
  w.document.write(printContents);
  w.print();
  w.close();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("id-template.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

@media print {
  #print {
    display: none;
  }
}

#print {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -4px;
}

div {
  padding-top: 204px;
}
```

```html
<div id="identity"> <span style="padding-left: 436px;">
    <form style="display: inline;"><input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" 
placeholder="PASSPORT PHOTO" style="border-color: grey; border-radius: 90px; height: 155px; width: 155px; text-align: center; font-family: monospace; font-size: 10px; margin-bottom: 7px" /></form></span>
  <br>
  <span style="padding-left: 370px">
    <form style="display: inline;"><input placeholder="YOUR NAME" style="border-color: grey; border-radius: 5px; height: 25px; width: 280px; text-align: center; font-family: monospace; font-size: 20px;" /></form></span>
</div><br>

<center><input type="button" id="print" onclick="print()" value="Print" /></center>
```

The two helps I need

1. I want the photograph to appear when selected from the user's device.
2. I want the print preview to show exactly what on the page.

This is the [id-template.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEVPG.jpg) I'm working with.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add an image how it wants to look like

Comment: @dev.skas I've added the template I'm working with.

Answer (score 2):

The html in your question has lots of noise and was relying on odd strategies for positioning.

For the sake of showing the core of the issue you are meant to solve, I stripped it down to the bare minimum. It won't perfectly match with your expectations but the css is well commmented so it will be easy for you to restyle it according to your needs.

### Displaying the picture loaded by user in an <input type=file>

Anyway the main problem there was how to show the picture in the file just loaded inside an `input type="file"` element.

The key is having a `change event` handler on your `input file` element so that when the user loads a new file, it will attempt to read it using a `FileReader` and will change the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element existing in the dom.

### .noprint class to style elements when @media print

I also added a class `noprint` to add to all the elements that will be hidden by the media query `@media print`. Such class is given to the `<input type="file">` and to the `<button>` for printing.

### References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

### Demo

I did a very small demo to show the point:

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  w = window.open();
  w.document.write(printContents);
  w.print();
  w.close();
}

/*shows inside #preview the picture loaded in the #photo element*/
function previewImage() {
  var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
  var file = document.getElementById('photo').files[0];
  
  //creates a FileReader with the onLoadEnd event handler
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function () {
    //..that will change the src attribute of the preview element to show the picture loaded
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }
  
  //if there's a file loaded
  if (file) {
    //unhide the #preview element
    preview.style.display = "block";
    //lets the FileReader reads the file loaded
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace; /* <----- here I set the font/size for all children in body */
  font-size: 18px; 
}

/*hides the .noprint elements when printing*/
@media print {
  .noprint {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

/*flex container*/
#identity{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em; /* <----- here I set space between elements in the container */
}

/*flex items*/
#identity > *{
  margin: 0 auto; /*horizontally centered*/
}

/*all input elements*/
input{
  border-color: grey;
  text-align: center;  
}

/*name input*/
#name{
  width: 30ch; /* <----- here I chose the name input to have 30ch*/
}

/*preview*/
#preview{
  width: 30%; /* <----- here I chose the preview to have 30% container width*/
}

#print{
  display: block;  
  margin: 1em auto 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
      
  <form id="identity">
    
    <input
      id="photo"
      class="noprint"
      name="photo"
      type="file"
      accept="image/jpeg" 
      placeholder="PASSPORT PHOTO"
      onchange="previewImage()">        
      
    <img id="preview" src="#" alt="Image preview" style="display:none;">

    <input
      id="name"
      name="name"
      placeholder="YOUR NAME">
  </form>
                
  <button type="button" id="print" class="noprint" onclick="print()">Print</button>

</body>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, it close to what I want but  to be more precise, I added the image I used as template. The print() seem still rearrange the page among other things.